# Eloquent query to get Highest and 2nd highest value in database

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

[image: This is the image of my dattabase]

I have a problem with Laravel Eloquent to get the subject name with the highest value and second highest value from the 'student_number' where the subject group = 'E1'.
This is what I have tried but it contains an error "max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array" and I don't know how to get the 2nd highest value of 'student_number'.

```
public function electiveGroup(){
    $E1 = FinalyearSubject::get()
        ->where('subject_group','=','E1')
        ->orWhere('student_number','=',max('student_number'));

    return view ('admin.elective')->with(compact('E1'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FinalyearSubject::where('subject_group', 'E1')
->orderBy('student_number', 'DESC')
->limit(2)
->get()
```

Explanation:

- Add filters
- Order them by student_number descending
- Take the top 2
- `get()` the result

In your example, the moment you are doing `FinalyearSubject::get()`, the query is already done. `get()` returns a `Collection` object (more like an enriched array). Everything you chain afterwards is calculated using Laravel's Collection utilities. `->get()` usually should be the last thing in your call so that you can do as much work in SQL as possible.

Answer (score 1):

> So, Question is you want maximum of all and 2nd maximum of subject
> group = 'E1'.

Max of all

```
FinalyearSubject::where('subject_group','E1')
->max('student_number');
```

---

2nd max of 'E1'

```
FinalyearSubject::where('subject_group','E1')
->OrderBy('student_number','desc')
->offset(1)
->limit(1)
->get();
```